# The link in the "possible rollback war" flag should be to the revision history, not the post

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, automatic-flags, rollback-wars

Currently when the system raises the "possible rollback war" flag it links to the **post**. This means that when we investigate we have to click through to the post, *then* click to view the revision history.

Can we have a direct link to the revision history please? It would save a click and make handling the flag much simpler.

Answer (score 5):

Suggested modification: leave the title as it is now, so that all post links in the flags view are consistent, but add a link in the flag itself.

Right now, in the flags list, the title of the post always links to the flagged question or answer.  Maintaining consistency is useful, but I agree we need a way to get to the revision history more efficiently.

There is another flag with similar properties.  When somebody trips the "too many rude comments" auto-flag, the flag is attached to the post with the most recent rude comment.  That's not ideal.  However, the flag text itself contains a link to the user's flagged comments.

(I prepared a screen shot, but even with parts elided I'm reluctant to show it.)

For the "rollback war" flag, that flag text should contain a link to the revision history.  That way flags with further information that isn't the post itself are consistent, in addition to the post links being consistent as I already said.

I don't currently have one to look at, but I seem to recall that the vandalism flag also contains links in, or just below, the flag.  Of course the flagged post is one of the interesting ones in that case, so that's a little different, but I bring it up to point out that we already have a pattern of useful links in the flags.  So we should do more of that here.